# javascript oop and this

Tags: oop, javascript-framework, javascriptmvc

Given the following code:

```
JE.events = {
  self: this,
  controller: {
    init: function(){            
        $(".monthheader").click(function () { 
            JE.events.model.get($(this).attr('title')); 
            return false;
        });

        return this;
    }
  },

  model: {
    get: function(monthnum){
        ...
    }
  }
```

}

How would i replace the call to

```
JE.events.model.get(..);
```

by something like

```
self.model.get(..);
```

The whole code is more or less in this gist https://gist.github.com/966270 . The idea is to create a really simple MVC in js (my first attempt) that i can reuse easily. Improvements are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JE.events = (function {
  // Create closure

  // Declare controller and model as local
  var Controller = {
    init: function(){            
        $(".monthheader").click(function () { 
            Model.get($(this).attr('title')); 
            return false;
        });

        return this;
    }
  }

  var Model = {
    get: function(monthnum){
        ...
    }
  }

  // return object thats assigned to JE.events
  return {
    controller: Controller,
    model: Model
  }

)();
```

You may also want to look at [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) or [spine](http://maccman.github.com/spine/) which are lightweight MVC frameworks.

They give you some simple abstractions and a lot of control. There also small and simple.

If I were to write a micro MVC framework from scratch it would converge to either backbone or spine so it might be better to use one of those two.